# Refresh layers when layer vibility changes

Tags: android, layout

I have a relative layout (RV1) where the top portion is a list view. Below that I have another relative view (R2) which holds a image and button.
Finally below R2, in R1 at the bottom there is an edit box and a button (B1).

Initially the R2 is set to visibility(gone) so that the list Sits just on top of the edit box. However when I press the button B1, I want the R2 to be visible and the list to now move above the R2.

In the xml settings, the list is set to be  above the R2 : android:layout_above="@id/R2Layout"
But since R2 is initially set to gone, the list sits on top of the edit box. Thats fine.

My problem is that once the button B1 is pressed the R2 becomes visible but the list does not make space to R2 and move above the R2. the R2 and list overlap each other.

I tried to make the whole view refresh itself by doing view.invalidate() but it did not work.

How do i solve this?

Below is the xml code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/r1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/b1"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

</EditText>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/r2"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/et"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button" /> 
</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/r2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="2.0sp"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:stackFromBottom="true" />

    <!-- Here is the view to show if the list is empty -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- If the list is empty because there are no files... -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:text="List empty"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should post the xml for your layout.

Comment: There is usually a problem in your layout in cases like this.  If other people can see the layout they can help you.

Comment: i have updated with the xml as advised. thanks

Comment: Did you set the visibility of r2 AND iv and b2 to visible? because you have both iv and b2 set to "gone". If you only set r2 to visible, its contents still won't show. Simply get rid of the visibility tags on iv / b2 and rely on their parent container visibility

Answer (score 0):

You can change your parent layout to `LinearLayout` and can wrap you `Button` and `EditText` in an `Horizontal Linear Layout`

Your final code will look something like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/r1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/r2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv"
            android:text="button"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:dividerHeight="2.0sp"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:stackFromBottom="true" />

        <!-- Here is the view to show if the list is empty -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- If the list is empty because there are no files... -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/empty_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="List empty"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```